# How to make data created at startup accessible for every controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I'm using OData with ASP.NET Core to work with Oracle database. I have a Startup.cs file where I configure authentication, build the model and load all dependencies. I am also reading a config file to load custom odata controllers identified like this :

```
CustomControllerList": [
{           
  "Assembly": "assemblyName",
  "PublicToken" : "123456789",
  "Controller": "UsersController",
  "Name": "Users",
  "Entity": "ModelNameSpace.UserEntity",
  "AccessRights" : [1, 2, 3]
},
{           
  "Assembly": "assemblyName",
  "PublicToken" : "123456789",
  "Controller": "GroupsController",
  "Name": "Users",
  "Entity": "ModelNameSpace.GroupsEntity",
  "AccessRights" : [4, 5, 6]
}]
```

I would like to store access rights related to a controller in order to check before each request if user is authorized.

Concerning code execution before each request, I saw that creating a new controller's functions attribute  like this

```
public class AccessRightsFilterAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                String username = Tools.GetUsernameFromToken(context.Controller as ControllerBase);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // do something after the action executes
        }
    }
```

My first question is : Is this the only one solution for executing code before each request ? Is there a way to avoid having to put attribute for every OData controller's functions ?

I can't connect to db inside Startup execution and custom OData controllers are not able to access the Startup project.

So my second question is : What is the best practice for reading this data from OData controllers ? I didn't found anything, my only choice is to write inside a file but I would like to know if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: A controller is used to parse the response from server.  It is not part of the request.  What is normally done is simply check that a response status is 200 OK.  Otherwise you will get a 400/500 error.  Even if the user has the access right you still can get error and the server access right may be different than the place where you store the rights.  You are creating two sets of the same access rights 1)  in the database 2) in your storage area and you have to make sure you update both when a user changes.  You are adding more work for the admin.

Comment: this is fairly easy, the most traditional way is use a ***global filter***. In that filter you check if the controller is from ODATA and perform your logic accordingly. Of course you should load the ODATA controller (names or types) into a HashSet so later you can check it quickly. The more advanced way is by modifying the application model (using a custom `IApplicationModelConvention`).